# Julia Box plots, not reading columns where the csv file column that the name has spaces and parenthesis but has no problem reading 1word column title

Tags: csv, julia, julia-plots

### So here's the code in Julia

using CSV

using DataFrames

using PlotlyJS

df= CSV.read("path", DataFrame)

plot(df, x=:Age, kind="box")

#I DO get the box plot for this one, because in the csv that column is headed with "Age"

plot(df, x=:Annual Income (k$), kind="box")

ERROR: syntax: missing comma or ) in argument list
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ none:1
#here I get an error asking about syntax, but I don't understand since the x= part is exactly what the column is labeled. If I try 'x=:Annual' I get a box plot of nothing, but the column title is "Annual Income (k$)".

Help is greatly appreciated!

Refrence: https://plotly.com/julia/box-plots/

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
plot(df, x=Symbol("Annual Income (k\$)"), kind="box")
```

The `:` syntax constructs a Symbol, but only upto the next space. So `:Annual Income (k$)` says to build the Symbol `Symbol("Annual")`, but then leaves the `Income (k$)` parts dangling. Instead you can explicitly construct the Symbol yourself like above.

The backslash before the `$` symbol is because Julia uses `$` usually for interpolation, and here we want to use the raw `$` character itself. You can also do `plot(df, x=Symbol(raw"Annual Income (k$)"), kind="box")` instead, as no interpolation happens inside `raw""` strings.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! That was so helpful.